# How to load runtime configuration and use it in an angular module?

Tags: angular, apollo, apollo-angular

Following the [Apollo Angular setup](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/setup/)

#### src/app/graphql.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { APOLLO_OPTIONS } from 'apollo-angular';
import { ApolloClientOptions, InMemoryCache, createHttpLink } from '@apollo/client/core';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-angular/http';

const uri = 'http://localhost:3000/graphql'; // <-- add the URL of the GraphQL server here
export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink): ApolloClientOptions<any> {
  return {
    link: httpLink.create({ uri }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  };
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
      useFactory: createApollo,
      deps: [HttpLink],
    },
  ],
})
export class GraphQLModule {}
```

This gives us a hardcoded URI variable that will obviously not work outside of local development. I would like to be able to change the URI by loading a configuration file at runtime, as opposed to build time (i.e. not using environment.ts). After reading [Runtime environment configuration with Angular](https://labs.thisdot.co/blog/runtime-environment-configuration-with-angular), this seems like a reasonable approach.

#### assets/config.json

Default configuration for local development that will be overridden on deployment

```json
{
  "apiUrl": "http://localhost:3000/graphql"
}
```

#### src/app/app-config.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

interface AppConfig {
  apiUri: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppConfigService {
  private appConfig: AppConfig;
  private http: HttpClient;

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  async loadAppConfig() {
    this.appConfig = await this.http.get('/assets/config.json')
      .toPromise() as AppConfig;
  }

  public get apiUri() {
    return this.appConfig.apiUri;
  }
}
```

#### src/app/app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { GraphQLModule } from './graphql.module';
import { AppConfigService } from './app-config.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, GraphQLModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide : APP_INITIALIZER,
      multi : true,
      deps : [AppConfigService],
      useFactory : (appConfigService : AppConfigService) =>  () => appConfigService.loadAppConfig()
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

So my question is, how do I use the `AppConfigService` in the `GraphQLModule` to get the `apiUrl` and set that to the `uri` in the `createApollo` factory function?

Comment: Hi bro ! Did you manage to sort it out ?

Comment: I have another twist. Some external modules are being used in my project :

`{
   provide : LOGO_REGISTRY,
   useValue :[
     {
       scope : 'XYZ',
       default: true,
       manifest : 'https://some-dev-url.com/XYZ'
},
]`


How can I use config URL instead of static Manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {APOLLO_OPTIONS} from 'apollo-angular';
import {ApolloClientOptions, InMemoryCache} from '@apollo/client/core';
import {HttpLink} from 'apollo-angular/http';
import {ConfigService} from './config.service';

export function createApollo(
  httpLink: HttpLink,
  configService: ConfigService
): ApolloClientOptions<any> {
  return {
    link: httpLink.create({uri: configService.apiUri}),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  };
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
      useFactory: createApollo,
      deps: [HttpLink, ConfigService],
    },
  ],
})
export class GraphQLModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a proxy instead? That would allow you to set the host you are poiting to before running your application.

Answer (score 0):

APP_INITIALIZER token is called at the start of your application and that is the best place where to setup the apollo client, but despite the official [apollo-angular documentation](https://apollo-angular.com/) recommends to use the APOLLO_OPTIONS token, if you need to setup the client in an async way I would suggest to use the *apollo.create* method in the map function of your promise:

**src/app/app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (appConfigService: AppConfigService, apollo: Apollo, httpLink: HttpLink) =>
        () => appConfigService.loadAppConfig()
          .pipe(
            map((appConfig: AppConfig) => {
              apollo.create({
                link: httpLink.create({
                  uri: appConfig.apiUrl,
                }),
                cache: new InMemoryCache(),
              });
            })
          ).toPromise(),
      deps: [AppConfigService, Apollo, HttpLink],
      multi: true
    },
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {
}
```